Is there a naming convention for the cubic roots of unity?
So, I was studying complex numbers and the topic of cubic roots of unity came up. My lecturer told me that the roots were $1$,$ω$ and $ω^2$.
My lecturer also told me that $ω$ and $ω^2$ had distinct values by convention which were  $$ω = \frac{-1}{2}+\frac{3^{1/2}i}{2}$$
$$ω^2 = \frac{-1}{2}-\frac{3^{1/2}i}{2}$$
I however, had the belief that they both were interchangeable values and there did not exist any convention system. When I asked him the reason for the convention then he told me that he too was told so by his lecturer but I couldn't find anything about such conventions.
So, does there truly exist such a convention and if not then what could be the possible reason behind having a convention for these values as they both are conjugates of each other anyways.

A trivial reason might be, that we draw these third roots of unity in the circle in the complex plane, and name them $e^{2\pi ik/3}$. After $1$ the next is $e^{2\pi i/3}$ for $k=1$, and why not name this one $\omega$. For $k=2$, the next one, one verifies that it must be equal to $\omega^2$ then. But we could have started with $k=2$ after $k=0$, that's true.

Cardano tried to introduce the names Cesare  and Lucrezia, but cooler heads prevailed

P. S.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cesare_Borgia   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucrezia_Borgia  and a bit later https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerolamo_Cardano

I'm not certain this is what you're asking for (so I'm only posting it as a comment, not an answer), but the lower case Greek letter $\omega$ is not tied to any particular value, in the way that $\pi$ and $e$ are (and even those letters can be given meanings different from the usual ones). That said, $\omega$ is often used to denote a primitive $n^\text{th}$ root of unity; but even then, $n$ may be any positive integer, not just $3.$ In brief: if you write the symbol $\omega$ in a mathematical text, you will need to define it; it won't be instantly understood in the way that $\pi$ and $e$ are.

@Will Jagy Hi Will ! Funny story about Cardano ... In France, in former times, the cubic roots of unity were named $1,j,j^2$. But it is no longer the case, surely due to the growing influence of electronicians using $j$ instead of $i$...

@JeanMarie Hi!  I like that , $1,j,j^2,$   quite sensible since we used $i$ for square root.

It's not mere convention. Of course 1 is a $nth$ root of unity for arbitrary $n$. Then let $\omega = e^{(2\pi i)/n}=\cos(2\pi/n)+i \sin (2 \pi  /n)$. So if $n=3, \omega = -1/2 + i(\sqrt{3}/2)$. Then one can show $\omega ^2$ is also a root of unity. We now have 3 cubic roots of unity. But as it happens, this holds for all positive integers $n$. The $n$ roots of unity form a multiplicative group that can be generated by the corresponding $\omega$. To generate the others, just calculate the various $\omega ^k$ for $0\le k<n$. If you start that sequence with $1$ then keep multiplying, you'll get the roots of unity evenly distributed around the unit circle in the complex plane.
The argument of a complex number $arg(x+iy)=\arctan(y/x)$. As you proceed   $1, \omega, \omega^2, ...$ you move counter clockwise in order.
So in the specific case of cubic roots of unity, you start with one, then your lecturer's $\omega$ then $\omega ^2$. That order is preferred because that's the order when you proceed counter clockwise along the roots on the unit circle.
Is a bit weird your lecturer couldn't see that.

Do you mean anti-clockwise from the real axis? It really doesn't matter, being a convention, not a rule, but I assumed you would number anti-clockwise as angles are measured this way in the unit circle.

Indeed! thanks. should be patched.
